# Getting FileNotFound Exception while creating connection to PostgreSQL in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio for first time and I am trying to create a simple application in which I will query database and display result on screen.

I have downloaded npgsql.dll file and I placed it in my local machine and I am adding the reference to it by right click and add reference method.

When I create connection and try to execute, it's giving FileNotFound exception at the db creation line. If I remove that line and display a simple message box then it's working fine. Can someone tell me what is happening wrong here?

Do I need to put .dll file at any specific location and add reference to it?

Here below I posted code part:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Npgsql;

namespace Test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres; Password=password; Database=test");
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I guess that you are missing dependencies for npgsql.dll

Comment: From package manager console run the following command 
Install-Package Npgsql -Version 3.0.5
Refer this docs https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console

Comment: @Soundararajan Thanks. It's working. Please port your answer.

Comment: You haven't posted code that creates a database. Please post the complete exception including the call stack, not just the type name. You can get the full exception with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: How did you add the PostgreSQL driver? With a package? When does the error occur? While debugging or during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are missing dependencies for npgsql.dll. From package manager console run the following command

> Install-Package Npgsql -Version 3.0.5

Refer this [docs](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console) for details on Package manager console.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **Npgsql** missed. You can download it from Nuget.

> Install-Package Npgsql -Version 3.0.5

[Npgsql 3.0.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/)

Comment: If the package was missing, how was the OP able to compile the code? If the OP forgot to copy the dll, the exception would be different, although deep down the inner exceptions tree there would be a FileNotFound exception

Comment: Post whole, complete exception or screenshot. Is Copy to Output Dierectory property of Npgsql  set to Copy Always?